# Find part of filename

Tags: find, directory, rename, search, for

Please help with my task:

I have a folder with three sub-folders containing six files each. There are two files in each sub-folder with :nopm in their file names.

I need to create a shell script that checks all the folders and their sub-folders. If there are any file names with :nopm as part of the name, this (:nopm) should be removed from the name. If there is another file with the same name, as in :nopm removed, it should be deleted and every interaction should be logged into a file named log.txt.

For example:

I have a directory: Example_September

In this directory I have three sub-directories:

```
fruit/
car/
vegetable/
```

These three directories have six files each:

```
fruit      : apple pear     banana  melon   grape :nopmlime
car        : fiat  mercedes ferrari audi   suzuki :nopmaudi
vegetables : bean  broccoli cabbage corn   carrot :nopmgarlic

In the directory fruit the script should rename :nopmlime to lime
In the directory car the script should delete :nopmaudi
```

All rename and remove must log to a .txt file like:

```
I remove the file(s)
I rename the file(s)
```

I should complete the task like this. Can you help to repair this?

```
for if find /data/irm/Example_September -name :nopm:
do mv filename1 filename2 
echo I rename the file. 
elif 
rm file 
echo I remove the file. 
fi >> /data/irm/Example_September/log.txt \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description in comments in script:

```
 # assign log file name into variable
 log_file_name=script.log
 # iterate over all files in this folder an its subfolders
 for fname in $(find . -type f) 
 do
      # check if current file name contains ":nopm" substring
      there_is_match=$(echo $(basename $fname) | grep ':nopm' | wc -l)
      # if yes value "1" will be assigned into there_is_match variable
      if [ $there_is_match -eq 1  ]  ; then
           # cut off ":nopm" substring - I use perl instead of sed because I find its regex nicer then sed's
           newname=$(echo $fname | perl -p -e 's/:nopm//g')
           # check if file without substring already exists
           if [ -e $newname ] ; then
                # if yes delete it and log it
                rm -f $newname
                echo "Deleted file $newname" >> $log_file_name
           fi
           # rename file and log it
           mv $fname $newname
           echo "Renamed file $fname to $newname" >> $log_file_name
      fi
 done
```

Please remember that `[ ]` brackets are shortcut for bash `test` command. It can compare numbers, strings and check some conditions on files and dirs.

Comment: It works!!! I just customize it and im done. Thanks a lot dude!